# Universal pool configure mining wallet

Tags: monerod

We have created a mining pool with Monero as a universal pool.
I want to know how long it will take to start digging and earn what is mined in my wallet.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzOHC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzOHC.png) Is it not possible to accumulate the mining due to an error in the wallet connection?

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have to find a block on your pool. Afterward, wait for the 60 blocks confirmation of the coinbase transaction.